# Fill a table with JQuery within an iframe

Tags: jquery

I am getting an XML document via an AJAX route, and have devised this function to display it in my HTML document.

What it *should* do is to add another row into my html table. That does not seem to work that way. In fact, it doesn't show any table at all (if I remove the stuff after $body.html, I at least get a table with the headings).

With some debugging, I have ensured that indeed the XML has result child elements.

Input data is

```
<resultset>
    <result>
         <gmk>23452455</gmk>
         <bes>Demo row 1</bes>
         <sat>773</sat>
    </result>
    <result>
         <gmk>457933555</gmk>
         <bes>Demo row 2</bes>
         <sat>543</sat>
    </result>
</resultset>
```

The function is

```
function showMultiResult(data) {

    var $frame = $('#multiResult');
    var doc = $frame[0].contentWindow.document;
    var $body = $('body',doc);
    $body.html('<table style="width:100%" id="resultTable"><tr><th>bes</th><th>GMK</th><th>sat</th></tr></table>');

    $(data).find("result").each(function(){

        var gmk = $(this).find("gmk").text();
        var bes = $(this).find("bes").text();
        var sat = $(this).find("sat").text();

        $('#resultTable').find('tbody')
            .append($('<tr>')
                .append($('<td>').text(gmk))
                .append($('<td>').text(bes))
                .append($('<td>').text(sat))
            );

    });
}
```

Comment: What is result? Also i dont see where you close the new row

Comment: 'result' is the child element in the XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this  [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/FXJrG/)

HTML

```
<table id="thetable">
<tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Middle row, will be deleted</td>
    <td>You will not see this</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
```

JQYERY

```
var data = {};
data.d = [{FirstName: 'Beaner', Age: '20'}, 
      {FirstName: 'Cheese', Age: '98'},
      {FirstName: 'Martin', Age: '45'}];

$('#thetable tr').not(':first').not(':last').remove();
var html = '';
for(var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++)
        html += '<tr><td>' + data.d[i].FirstName + '</td><td>' + data.d[i].Age + '</td></tr>';
$('#thetable tr').first().after(html);
```